# How to put a group of changes to an array and then print all of them as one in C

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I'm solving a coding problem currently. I must encipher a code and change words into other encoded words. I know I can check and print each character. However, I want to try to save the result of the checking of each character to an array, and then later I want to just print it.

Below is the full code... I deeply appreciate it if anyone can help me answer my question, or if it is even possible.

```
//one command line argument with the type int

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //setting condition that: K = +; if more or less than one, immediate error message, return 1
    //if not decimal return = usage ./caesar. key, return value 1 to main
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error 404 : \n");
        return 1;
    }
    //main program
    else if ( argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
    {
        int k = atoi(argv[1]);                                                     
        string pltext = get_string("plaintext: ");                                  //getting input for the plain text
        char cptext[]

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(pltext) ; i < n; i++)                            //turning pltext to integer
        {
            if (pltext[i] >= 'a' && pltext[i] <= 'z')
            {
                cptext[i] = ((pltext[i] - 'a' + k)%26)+'a';                           //shifting the integer with k (lowercase)
            }
            else if (pltext[i] >= 'A' && pltext[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                cptext[i] = ((pltext[i] - 'A' + k)%26)+'A';                           //shifting the integer with k (uppercase)
            }
            else
            {
                cptext[i] = pltext[i];                                                //other symbol stays
            }
        }
    //print out result
    string cptext = ("test");
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cptext[]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allocate an array according to the number of elements to be stored.

```
char cptext[]
```

should be

```
char cptext[strlen(pltext) + 1]; // +1 for terminating null-character
```

(variable-length array introduced in C99)

and

```
string cptext = ("test");
printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cptext[]);
```

should be

```
cptext[strlen(pltext)] = '\0'; // terminate the string
printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cptext); // remove extra []
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question! I was anxious on whether anyone would answer my question. I tried the revision and it works! but I don't understand the function of the last part where you write ** cptext[strlen(pltext)] = '\0' **. I tried removing it and it works fine too. I think in the original code it was a mistake on my part and you tried to correct it?
Anyway, thank you once again!